# Error about missing (sql) field "pw_sieve" under pigeonhole

Tags: dovecot, login, sieve

Yesterday I installed the latest updates of dovecot 2.3 and pigeonhole 0.5.0 in the hope that some sieve-bugs have been fixed in the meantime.

However, now I get the error

"**dovecot: auth-worker(###): Warning: mysql: Query failed, retrying: Unknown column 'pw_sieve' in 'field list'**"

in my mail logs when I try to log in via manage-sieve using IMAP-login.

I don't know from where he gets this. I searched the web, my config files and even the sourcecode of dovecot and pigeonhole but nowhere is a clue to "pw_sieve".

Does anybody know how to fix this?

TIA!

Comment: First you have to run `grep -R pw_sieve *` in the directory where dovecot's config reside.

Comment: I tried this with no result...

Comment: Make a broader search across the whole `/etc`. Seems like you have different configurations mixed up. You have database structure from one howto while queries are from the other, i guess.